# will win vs are going to win in context

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

In exam (Egyptian GSEC English exam) today

> Liverpool's players are known to be skilled. They (will win - are going to win) the match easily.

This question was in my exam, I already answered it "will win", because it's not an evidence, skill doesn't mean that I'm going to win, but I'm not sure about that.

What's the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no correct, or incorrect, answer (in the real world. There probably is in your test!)

In that context, "they will win" seems more natural.

"They are going to win" is possible, but carries some extra meaning; but the extra meaning is not specific. For example, it might be a surprised prediction ("I didn't think it was possible, but now I'm sure") or a fervent wish ("I really really want them to win, so I'm going to be positive and predict it").